# Why is direct base class inacessible from a ctor-initializer?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

While compiling the code:

```
struct A{ };

struct B : public A{ };

struct C : public A, public B{ C(); };

C::C(): A(){ }

int main()
{
    C c;
}
```

a compiler gave me the following warning:

```
main.cpp:8:8: warning: direct base 'A' inaccessible in 'C' due to ambiguity
 struct C : public A, public B{ C(); };
```

So why is the direct base class inacessible? I expected it to be found instead of the direct one of `B`.

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/154ff9736a32fefe

Comment: Note that your code does compile. In the *ctor-initializer* there is no problem at all: the compiler only expects to see a direct base or virtual base there. Elsewhere, you will have a problem, for the reasons discussed in the duplicate.

Comment: For 'C' : base-class 'A' is already a base-class of 'B'